# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox How do you extract the text within HTML element tags?

Tags: html, perl, web-scraping, www-mechanize, www-mechanize-firefox

Good Day,

How do you print the text of an `HTML` tag with `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`?

I have tried:

```
    print $_->text, '/n' for $mech->selector('td.dataCell');

    print $_->text(), '/n' for $mech->selector('td.dataCell');


    print $_->{text}, '/n' for $mech->selector('td.dataCell');

    print $_->content, '/n' for $mech->selector('td.dataCell');
```

Remember I do not want `{innerhtml}`, but that does work btw.

```
print $_->{text}, '/n' for $mech->selector('td.dataCell');
```

The above line does work, but output is just multiple `/n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I have is to use:

```
my $element = $mech->selector('td.dataCell');

my $string = $element->{innerHTML};
```

And then formatting the html within each `dataCell`

Answer (score 3):

```
my $node = $mech->xpath('//td[@class="dataCell"]/text()');

print $node->{nodeValue};
```

Note that if you're retrieving text interspersed with other tags, like "Test_1" and "Test_3" in this example...

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form name="input" action="demo_form_action.asp" method="get">
      <input name="testRadioButton" value="test 1" type="radio">Test_1<br>
      <input name="testRadioButton" value="test 3" type="radio">Test_3<br>
      <input value="Submit" type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

You need to refer to them by their position within the tag (taking any newlines into account):

```
$node = $self->{mech}->xpath("//form/text()[2]", single=>1);

print $node->{nodeValue};
```

Which prints "Test_1".

Comment: Made my day !! Boy.

Answer (score 1):

I would do :

```
print $mech->xpath('//td[@class="dataCell"]/text()');
```

using a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression

Comment: Fixed a misstake in Xpath expression

Comment: It prints out 'Mozrepl::RemoteObject::Instance=HASH(s0mehex)' not the text inside the dataCells

Comment: @surfer190 You have to add `type => $mech->xpathResult('STRING_TYPE')` as another parameter

Answer (score 0):

Either:

`$element->{textContent};`

or

`$element->{innerText};`

will work.